# How to sum 2 rows group by 2 different column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

How to sum 2 rows group by 2 different columns `Settlement_Currency` and `DateOfPayment` in SQL Server?

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IfEL.jpg][1]

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    r.CreateDate as DateOfPayment,
    r.Settlement_Currency,
    (SELECT DISTCINT
        (SELECT COUNT(j2.Settlement_Currency)
         FROM FWReconciliation AS j2
         WHERE j.Settlement_Currency = j2.Settlement_Currency) AS crc
     FROM FWReconciliation j
     WHERE j.CreateDate >= '2019-07-17' 
       AND j.CreateDate <= '2019-07-25' 
       AND j.Settlement_Currency = r.Settlement_Currency
     GROUP BY
         j.CreateDate, j.Settlement_Currency) AS TotalTrading,
        (select  distinct
            (SELECT distinct sum(Convert(decimal, j2.Payment_Amount))
                FROM FWReconciliation AS j2
                WHERE j.Settlement_Currency = j2.Settlement_Currency) as crc
        from FWReconciliation j
        where Convert(varchar(30), j.CreateDate, 111) >= '2019-07-17' and j.CreateDate <= '2019-07-25' and j.Settlement_Currency = r.Settlement_Currency
        group by  j.CreateDate, j.Settlement_Currency) as TotalPay

FROM FWReconciliation r
```

Comment: Please provide more information around what you are trying to achieve. Which columns do you need to group by, what are you summing, what do you expect to happen to other rows?
Some sample output of what you are trying to achieve is required.

Comment: sum 2 rows group by 2 different column Settlement_Currency and DateOfPayment in sqlserver

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: I need to sum Payment_Amount from  rows same column Settlement_Currency and  CreateDate. 
If 2 rows have same Create  and Settlement_Currency, i want to sum  Payment_Amount into 1 row.
please send me some ideas.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are massively over complicating what you think you need.  Is it as simple as:

```
SELECT Settlement_Currency, CAST(Trans_Time as DATE), SUM(PaymentAmount)
FROM FWReconcilliation
GROUP BY Settlement_Currency, CAST(Trans_Time as DATE)
```